# Рассчитать сумму значений произвольных полей в разных постах

Tags: php, wordpress

Приветствую!

Ситуация следующая. Одни посты выводятся внутри других постов.

1. Если значение произвольного поля `parent-id_1` одного поста (предложение)
   совпадает с `$post->id` основного поста,  пост-предложение выводится
   внутри основного поста.
2. Все посты-предложения имеют дополнительное произвольное поле цена
   `order_price` с разными значениями.

Необходимо вывести общую сумму опубликованных постов (предложений) внутри основного поста. yadi.sk/i/Blqy-3LR3Mkdzg

Спасибо.

```
/*цикл по выводу предложений на странице исполнителя. Добавляет произвольное поле parent-task-id_1 в предложение исполнителю */

function the_tasklist_for_offer_1(){
    global $post;

    $tasks = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'task',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'parent-task-id_1',
                'value' => $post->ID
            )
        )
    ));

    if(!$tasks){

        echo '<p>Предложений пока нет.</p>';

    }else{

        echo '<pre style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: green;"><strong>Поступившие предложения:</strong></span></pre>';

        echo '<div class="task-list">';

        foreach($tasks as $post){ setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <div class="offer-task">
            <div class="task-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <b><?php// the_title() ?></b>
            </div>
            <div class="task-content"><?php get_template_part('content-except',''); ?></div>
            </div>
            </a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php echo '</div>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

    }}
```

/*Код поста в котором осуществлен вывод предложений за счет функции the_tasklist_for_offer_1() */

```
    <?php
        if(have_posts())
        {
        while(have_posts()) { the_post();?>
        <!--Blog Author-->
                <div class="blog-author">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                        <span class="inline"> 
                        <?php $action = rcl_get_time_user_action($post->post_author); 
                        echo rcl_get_miniaction($action);?></span>
                            <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID') , 200); ?>
                            <p>Автор: <b><?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name',$post->post_author);?></b></p>
                <span  class="rating-author"><p>Рейтинг автора: <?php echo  rcl_rating_block(array('value'=>rcl_get_user_rating($post->post_author)));?></p></span>
                <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'));?>"><div class="point-task">Отзывы об авторе</div></a>
                              <?php rcl_get_author_block(); ?>
                              </br>
                              <?php echo do_shortcode('[add-bookmark]');?>
                            </br>
                            <?php if($post->post_author==$user_ID) 
            $views = '<a href="#" id="get-views-history" data-post="'.$post->ID.'"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>';
            $views = get_post_total_views($post->ID);?>
                <div class="task-metadata">
        <div class="task-meta-list">
            <p class="task-meta">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o rcl-icon"></i><?php echo mysql2date('d-m-Y', $post->post_date);?>                
            </p>          
            <p class="task-meta">
               <i class="fa fa-eye rcl-icon"></i>Просмотров: <?php echo $views; ?>                    
            </p>
            <p class="task-meta">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o rcl-icon"></i>Срок сбора: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'order_time_group',1);?> дн 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <?php //echo rcl_get_author_block ();?>                             
            <!-- Blog Area -->
            <div class="<?php appointment_post_layout_class(); ?>" >


        <?php get_template_part('content-new-group',''); ?> <!-- вывод метаданных предложения в файле content-new-group -->
                                                                <!--
                                                                <div class="task-metadata">
                                                                <div class="task-price">
                                                                Бюджет <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'byudzhet_82',1);?><?php echo rcl_get_primary_currency(1);?>
                                                                <span class="order_price">  Собрано <?php
                                                                $metakey = get_post_meta($post->ID,'order_price',true);

                                                                $suma = array($metakey);
                                                                echo " = " . array_sum($suma) . "\n";?> 
                                                                <?php echo rcl_get_primary_currency(1);?></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                -->
                <!--Blog Author-->
                <!---вывод постов предложение автору--->
    <div class="script-block">
<a onclick="hidetxt('div4'); return false;" href="#" rel="nofollow"><class="button"/><h5><i class="fa fa-pencil rcl-icon"></i><b>Оставить предложение автору</b></h5></a>
<div style="display:none;" id="div4">
<!-- форма пыбликаций-->
<?php echo do_shortcode('[order-form]');?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- вывод пыбликаций (предложений)-->
<?php the_tasklist_for_offer_1(); ?>
                <!--/Blog Author-->
                <?php }} ?> 
                </div>
            <!-- /Blog Area -->         

            <!--Sidebar Area-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: Покажите свой код.

Comment: /*вывод постов внутри другого поста*/function the_tasklist_for_offer(){
 global $post;
 
 $tasks = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'task',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'meta_query' => array(
   array(
    'key' => 'parent-task-id',
    'value' => $post->ID
   )
  )
 ));
 
 if(!$tasks){
  
   
  foreach($tasks as $post){ setup_postdata($post); ?>
  
   <?php the_excerpt();; ?>
   
  <?php } ?>
  
  
  wp_reset_postdata();
  
 }

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код в вопрос, отредактировав его.

Comment: /*Вывод постов */ 
function the_tasklist_for_offer(){
 global $post;
 
 $tasks = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'task',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'meta_query' => array(
   array(
    'key' => 'parent-task-id',
    'value' => $post->ID
   )
  )
 ));
 
 if(!$tasks){
  
   
  foreach($tasks as $post){ setup_postdata($post); ?>
  
   <?php the_excerpt();; ?>
   
  <?php } ?>
  
  
  wp_reset_postdata();
  
 }

}
// 'parent-task-id' указанных постов совпадает с id постов в которых они выводятся. Еще выводимые посты имеют произвольное поле order_price(цена).

Comment: У вас есть кнопка редактирования ВОПРОСА.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения значения произвольного поля следует использовать функцию get_post_meta(). Общую сумму можно вернуть как результат работы функции.

```
function the_tasklist_for_offer() {
    global $post;

    $tasks = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'task',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'parent-task-id',
                'value' => $post->ID,
            ),
        )
    ) );

    $total = 0;
    if ( $tasks ) {
        foreach ( $tasks as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            the_excerpt();
            $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true );
            $total += $price;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Результат подсчета можно вывести в нужном месте:

```
$sum = the_tasklist_for_offer();
echo $sum;
```

Comment: сумму значений произвольного поля 'order_price' необходимо получить не в выводимых постах, а в посте, в котором осуществлен вывод этих постов https://yadi.sk/i/Blqy-3LR3Mkdzg .....дело в том,  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'order_price', true ) выводит значение текущего поста, а не постов в нем размещенных.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что за картинка? Какой код ее выводит? Дайте ваш код полностью, с "выводимыми постами" и "постом, в котором осуществлен вывод этих постов". Я вам основную идею показал - get_post_meta().

Comment: я поправил описание вопроса

Comment: ну а вернуть подсчитанный $total ведь не сложно? внес изменения в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.